# Компиляция пакета заглушки Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Помогите скопилировать пакет-заглушку kmod
https://github.com/uli-heller/kmod
Пакет нужен для установки новых версий ядра на старую Ubuntu 12.04
Как не пытался ничего не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проделано только что в docker-контейнере ubuntu:12.04

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get -y install build-essential dh-make wget unzip
...
$ wget https://github.com/uli-heller/kmod/archive/master.zip
...
$ unzip master.zip
...
$ (cd kmod-master && dpkg-buildpackage)
...
dpkg-buildpackage: full upload; Debian-native package (full source is included)
$ ls
kmod-master
kmod_0.1-0dp01~precise01.dsc
kmod_0.1-0dp01~precise01.tar.gz
kmod_0.1-0dp01~precise01_all.deb
kmod_0.1-0dp01~precise01_amd64.changes
master.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите как ставятся аналогичные версии на последних актуальных версиях Ubuntu, узнайте как используются два файла из архива "control" и "rules". Думаю найдёте решение.

Comment: Слушай ты прям бог советов, я уже ставил dh-make, он отрабатывает нормально, но вот сам сборщик пакета bzr, не хочет собирать пакет ссылаясь на отсутствие файла, хотя фактически он есть